# Android custom migration Sqlcipher from 3 to 4

Tags: android, database-migration, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I upgraded Sqlcipher for Android from 3.5.7 to 4.1.3 in my app.

For the existing database, which has been created with Sqlcipher 3, I need a custom migration as it is based on custom parameters, as also the option 3 of [this article](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/upgrading-to-sqlcipher-4/3283) explains.

I'm getting this exception when I try to open the database.

```
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
```

This is my code:

```
        SQLiteDatabaseHook mHook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook() {
            public void preKey(SQLiteDatabase database) {
                database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA kdf_iter=1000;");
                database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA cipher_default_kdf_iter=1000;");
                database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA cipher_page_size = 4096;");
            }

            public void postKey(SQLiteDatabase database) {
                database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA cipher_compatibility=3;");
            }
        };

        // this line generate the exception
        SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(oldDatabaseFile.getAbsolutePath(), password, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, mHook);
        ...
        // migration code with ATTACH, sqlcipher_export etc... 
        ...
```

The file exists and the password is correct: The same piece of code works if I downgrade the Sqlcipher library. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found the error:

I created the database with sqlchipher 3 using the parameter `cipher_page_size = 4096`, but it is not accepted as the default value was used.

Trying now to migrate, specifying the parameter I thought was used, it didn't work. I just had to remove this parameter and put everything in `postKey` method

```
private final SQLiteDatabaseHook mHook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook() {
    public void preKey(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    }

    public void postKey(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA cipher_compatibility=3;");
        database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA kdf_iter=1000;");
        database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA cipher_default_kdf_iter=1000;");
    }
};
```

Comment: That took a long time to find the error. I am having some issues opening the migrated db in sqlite db browser. Were you able to open it after migrating?

Comment: Yes look at my own answer

Comment: @Gigi - do we need to use this mHook while opening db every time or only first time after app is upgraded?